# The eigenvalue of opencv and matlab are different, why?

Tags: matlab, opencv, pca

I am trying a example of PCA and I find the eigenvalues using the MATLAB are different from the values using OpenCV, while the eigenvectors are same.  Does anyone know why?  What's the difference between this two algorithms?

My MATLAB code is as follows：

```
a=[-14.8271317103068,-3.00108550936016,1.52090778549498,3.95534842970601;...
   -16.2288612441648,-2.80187433749996,-0.410815700402130,1.47546694457079;...
   -15.1242838039605,-2.59871263957451,-0.359965674446737,1.34583763509479;...
   -15.7031424565913,-2.53005662064257,0.255003254103276,-0.179334985754377;...
   -17.7892158910100,-3.32842422986555,0.255791146332054,1.65118282449042;...
   -17.8126324036279,-4.09719527953407,-0.879821957489877,-0.196675865428539;...
   -14.9958877514765,-3.90753364293621,-0.418298866141441,-0.278063876667954;...
   -15.5246706309866,-2.08905845264568,-1.16425848541704,-1.16976057326753;];

[covEigvec, ~,covEigval] = princomp(a, 'econ')；
```

My OpenCV code is as follows:

```
cv::Mat sampleset(nums,dim,CV_32FC1,data);
cv::PCA *pca = new cv::PCA(sampleset,cv::Mat(),CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW,redDim);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those eigenvalues are different, up to a scale.

because opencv scales the data while computing the covariance matrix.

see `core/src/matmul.cpp:2226` (roughly here)

```
    mulTransposed( data, _covar, ((flags & CV_COVAR_NORMAL) == 0) ^ takeRows,
    mean, (flags & CV_COVAR_SCALE) != 0 ? 1./nsamples : 1, ctype );
```

this function will eventually call `gemm`, with its fifth argument as scaling factor

Comment: Thank u. So is there any problem when I want to use the eigenvalues from OpenCV to do some process, such as whitening

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake, the scaling in opencv is instead a normalization term. see the "estimation" section [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix). Note that there are two types of denominator: (n-1) and (n) which are used by matlab and opencv, respectively.

Comment: Thank u again. So which one is correct when I want to use the eigenvalues or just no differnce?

Comment: That depends. You can easily convert the eigenvalues by multiplying them with sqrt(n/(n-1)), and see if that make any difference to your application.